# how to check the text inside div element by using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I am completely new to java and I want to check if the text inside div element equals to a specific value by giving the xpath. For example if the text equals to "value 1" the test passes other wise it shows a message. I am not sure how to use assertEquals with xpath. can you give me some hints?

```
<div id="indicator">value 1 </div>
```

thanks

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Answer (score -1):

Are you using javascript or jsp?

Any Case is easy, this will return your value:

```
$("#MyId").val();
```

In your case it would be:

```
$("#indicator").val();
```

Comment: Question is tagged "java"

Comment: Yes, But he says he is using Xpath, which is basically javascript, If you can directly do this request using JAVA, let us know.. good luck :)

Comment: Xpath is not necessarily Javascript. It's XPath :-) And I guess every reasonable programming language in the world supports it, even Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Comment: Thanks but my main problem is using assertEqual in java, to check if the return value is true or n ot

Comment: but do you have the string already in some variable? where you able to get both String to compare?